# Check if a json key is a complex object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, key, business-process-management, hasownproperty

USING IBP BPM 8.6:

I have a Json object as follows:

```
tw.local.stringifiedJSON = "{"name":"ahmed","age":"20","job":{"salary":"1000","position":"developer"}}";
```

I parsed into a javascript object:

```
var parsedJSONTW= JSON.parse(tw.local.stringifiedJSON);
```

I want to check if each key is complex (nested or has other keys and values in it like "job") or flat (has a value only like "name")

```
var finObj={};
   var i;

  for ( i in parsedJSONTW) {         
    if (finObj[i] === undefined) {  finObj[i] = {};  }

tw.local.propertiesOfObject=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parsedJSONTW[i]);

if(tw.local.propertiesOfObject==null || tw.local.propertiesOfObject.listLength==0)  
    {
     finObj[i]= parsedJSONTW[i]; //expected to have name and age fields only

    }
```

Using object.getOwnProperty() doesn't work with a flat object and gives the error of "expected an object but found a string"

Answer (score 0):

You can use "typeof" for this:

```
let a = {"name":"ahmed","age":"20","job":{"salary":"1000","position":"developer"}}

for(let k in a){
  console.log(typeof a[k])
  if(typeof a[k] === 'object'){
    console.log("nested")
  }
  else{
    console.log("flat")
  }
}
```

Comment: so you did not parse the json string first?